# OpenJDK breaks on processWorkerExit with no breakpoint

Tags: tomcat, java, breakpoints

I'm running tomcat 7.0.21 on OpenJDK

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.9) (6b20-1.9.9-0ubuntu1~10.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

in debug mode via Eclipse.

Periodically after serving an arbitrary number of requests, OpenJDK starts to break at:

[image: break in ThreadPoolExecutor]

At this point there is very little stack left, usually:

[image: stack position]

and very little to go on as far as what might have cause the issue...

Anyone have any insight on what might be happening?

Comment: It happens for me with Oracle Java 7, too (even at the same line of ocde). dlawrence's answer solved it.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In debug mode in eclipse by default, break on uncaught exceptions is checked. Since you don't have a catch method here, it's likely that an uncaught exception is being thrown and the debugger is breaking for you immediately before the exception is thrown. You can turn it off in preferences under Java->Debug.

Comment: That was it! Thanks dlawrence!

Comment: `Window > Preferences > Java > Debug`
Just because I remember being a complete newb to eclipse and when I found something useful I just wanted people to provide as much detail as possible when answering

Comment: The same happens in Netbeans :)

Answer (score 3):

Spot on, still relevant in 2015 with latest Eclipse too. Make sure to keep the check-box under green highlight circle to be unchecked.
I am adding image to highlight the change[image]